# Rmarkdown glossary

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, glossary

I've a simple question. How i create a glossary with Rmarkdown / knitr. I work with RStudio.

I try this but without success

```
\usepackage{glossaries}
```

in a header.tex and in rmd file

```
Glossary
--------

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{score_r1_ch1}
{
name=zscore,
description={ description here}
}
\printglossaries
```

Thanks

Comment: First of all, there are `{}` brackets missing: `name={zscore}`. Other than that, if you have a look at this [beginners' guide](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf), section 4, you'll know that you have to run LaTeX twice in order to make a glossary, which frankly, I don't know how to do.

Comment: I have precisely the same issue... As @jmjr points out, you have to run LaTeX twice.  I don't know how to do that from `rmarkdown` either.

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party, but the following might interest others on the search for creating a *glossary* in `RMarkdown` when rendering to `.pdf`:

One can use [`definition lists`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#definition-lists) to create glossaries. This is part of a `.rmd` file:

```
# Glossary {-}

Foo

:   description of foo

Bar

:   descirption of bar
```

This renders to:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't _require_ blank line before `:`, but does require at least one space between `:` and definition.